# Read CSV File Faster Using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a CSV file, which is of huge size(i.e. 24 GB). What are the ways we can read it faster using python? I have to read it repetitively

Comment: The easiest way is using [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/)

Comment: My python is inbuilt with the SAP application. there I can install only standard libraries, Not sure if PyPy will be installable there, can you suggest anything specific to file read